# Updating a Human Task Status

Tags: jbpm

I have run into a scenario where I create a process instance and subsequently start process on the task.

Is there a way to update the task status using the kContext from within the bpmn? (Moving the task from Reserved to In Progress)

Thanks.

Comment: Upon investigation my concept was flawed.
The solution was to create a custom WorkItemHandler to perform my desired operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon investigation my concept was flawed.

The solution was to create a custom WorkItemHandler to perform my desired operation.